# Showing date file was locked in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, visualsvn-server

In VisualSVN Server or in Tortoise SVN, is there a way to show when a file was locked using Tortoise SVN functionality?

Workflow:

1. Tortoise SVN > Add (on Date D)
2. Tortoise SVN > Commit (on date D)
3. Tortoise SVN > Get Lock (on date D+1)
4. Tortoise SVN > Check for Modifications

Notice how the date is not D+1, but instead it's D.

Comment: Are you sure it's the date in which you locked the file?  Try the workflow over multiple days.  Also, what version are you using?

Comment: I was mistaken, CfM doesn't show the lock date, I was misremembering. It shows the revision date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Date` on the 'Check for Modifications' dialog is `Last Changed Date`. It's not related to the lock. However, the columns are customizable. If you right-click a column header, you will be able to add and remove columns. If you want to see column with the `Lock Created` date on this dialog, you can add the `Lock Date` column.

[image: columns]